# Checking for complements in $\sigma$-algebras?

Tags: measure-theory

In the context of sigma-algebras one may need to check that the complement of some set belongs to the $\sigma$-algebra.

If

$$\Omega=\{0,1\},$$

then e.g. $2^\Omega=\{\emptyset, \{0\}, \{1\}, \{0,1\}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$.

But what is the complement of $\{0,1\}$ (or any element of $2^\Omega$ for that matter) that must belong to $2^\Omega$?

Answer (score 1):

The complement of $A\subseteq \Omega$ is just $\Omega\setminus A=\{\,x\in\Omega\mid x\notin A\,\}$. Specifically, the complement of $\Omega$ is $\emptyset$. (Recall that in set theory the notion of "complement" makes sense only in relation to a *base* or *universal* set; in this context that is "of course"  $\Omega$).

Comment: Well this clears it. I was confused about whether the complement is "in the set" or should include some "outer set" such as $\mathbb{R}$.